# shift power mod 1 of the cantor set by an irrational number and their intersections

Tags: calculus, general-topology, number-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $C$ be the Cantor ternary set and consider the shift $T_a$ mod 1 of the interval $[0,1]$ for an irrational number $a\in[0,1]$. I'm wondering whether $T_a^k(C)\cap T_a^l(C)=\emptyset$, $k,l\in {\Bbb Z}$, $k\neq l$.

Comment: To be sure that I understand your notation: isn’t $T_a^k$ just $T_{ka}$?

Comment: $T^k_a=(T_a)^k$, the $k$-power

Comment: That’s what I thought. Isn’t that the same as $T_{ka}$?

Comment: I don't know, maybe not because of "mod 1", consider $C$ as living on the circle

Comment: I was taking that into account. You’re shifting it $a$ units around the circle $k$ times. That’s the same as shifting it $ka$ units once.

Comment: It corresponds to the rotation of the angle $2\pi\a$

Comment: then $T^k_a$ corresponds to the rotation of the angle $2\pi ka$

Comment: Obviously I’m using a circle of circumference $1$. If you want to complicate matters by using one of radius $1$ instead, that’s fine, but notice that the substance of my statement is still true: $2\pi ka$ is simply $k$ times $2\pi a$. As I was trying to hint, most of the complication in your question is illusory. You’re really just asking whether $T_a[C]\cap C=\varnothing$ for irrational $C$. The answer is *no*, because $C-C=[-1,1]$.

Comment: $C-C$ is not $T_a(C)\cap C$, where a is for example an "very small" irrational number.....

Comment: Of course not. I never said that it was. $C-C=\{x-y:x,y\in C\}$. Now think about why the fact that this is $[-1,1]$ implies that the answer to your question is *no*.

Comment: I'm asking just for that explanation if there is (it seems to me that you also don't have that, otherwise you've answered the question directly with that)

Comment: I thought that you might like to try to answer your own question, once you saw how it could be simplified. I’ve added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that for $k\in\Bbb Z$ we have $T_a^k=T_{ka}$. Thus, the question boils down to asking whether $T_{ka}[C]\cap T_{\ell a}[C]=\varnothing$, which is equivalent to asking whether $T_{(k-\ell)a}[C]\cap C=\varnothing$. We might as well simply ask whether $T_a[C]\cap C=\varnothing$. Let $\alpha=a-\lfloor a\rfloor$, the fractional part of $a$. It’s well-known that $C-C=[-1,1]$, so $\alpha\in C-C$, i.e., there are $x,y\in C$ such that $\alpha=x-y$. But then

$$x=y+\alpha\equiv(y+a)\!\!\!\pmod1\;,$$

so $x\in T_a[C]\cap C\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: everything is clear now (thank you), but I've the following related question: it is known the cardinality of $T_a(C)\cap C$ when $a\in[0,1]$ is irrational?

Comment: @francesco: You’re welcome. That’s a good question; I don’t offhand know the answer, but I’d almost bet that it’s $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}$. The intersection is a closed set, so it must be countable or have cardinality $2^\omega$, and I’d be very much surprised if it could be countable.

Comment: yes Brian, thank you. Another question is (in case it is not countable): what is $\mu(T_a(C)\cap C)$ where $\mu$ is the Cantor ternary probability measure (still in case $a$ irrational)

Comment: @francesco: I’d have to give that some serious thought, and if I have time, I will. I suggest, though, that you post it as a separate question, so that more people see it.

Comment: Thank you Brian, keep in contact, if I find something about that I'll keep you informed