# If $A$ has measure zero, then is there $x$ such that $A \cap (A-x)=\emptyset$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ has Lebesgue measure zero, is it always possible to find an $x$ such that $A \cap (A-x)=\emptyset$?

This is one of those things that seems *reasonable*, but I'm worried about pathologies. For instance, if $A$ were a group, then the result is obvious. One might consider the group generated by $A$, but this may be too large. E.g. if $A$ is the standard Cantor set on $[0,1]$, then the subgroup generated by $A$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why is it obvious for $A$ a group?

Comment: @IgorRivin If $A$ is a group, then $A-x$ is a coset and distinct cosets are disjoint, so as long as $A \neq \mathbb{R}$ there are at least two cosets. Since $A$ has measure zero, it cannot be all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is x a point or a set ? And (A-x) is A without x ?

Comment: @zwim My reading is: $x$ is a point, and $A-x$ is the additive (as opposed to set-theoretic) difference).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not always possible. Let $A$ be the union of concentric spheres around the origin, with (all) positive rational radii. This counterexample works in all dimensions greater than $1.$ In $\mathbb{R},$ I am not sure if there is a counterexample (I am guessing yes, but not seeing it).

Comment: For $n=1$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023116/shift-power-mod-1-of-the-cantor-set-by-an-irrational-number-and-their-intersecti shows that $C+\mathbb{Z}$, where $C$ is the Cantor set, provides a counterexample as well.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a complete metric space and suppose $A,B$ are dense $G_\delta$ subsets of $X.$ Then $A\cap B \ne \emptyset.$ The proof is simple: Suppose $A\cap B = \emptyset,$ dust off DeMorgan's laws, and finish it off with Baire to reach a contradiction.

Now $\mathbb R^d$ is a complete metric space, and it has lots dense $G_\delta$ subsets of measure $0.$ Let $A$ be any one of these. Because translation is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^d$ onto itself, every $A-x$ is also a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb R^d. $ From the first paragraph we conclude $A\cap (A-x) \ne \emptyset$ for each $x\in \mathbb R^d.$